# Django: get_object_or_404 for ListView

Tags: django

I have the following ListView. I know about `get_object_or_404`. But is there a way to show a 404 page if the *object* doesn't exist?

```
class OrderListView(ListView):

    template_name = 'orders/order_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=self.kwargs['order_reference'],
        )
```

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can raise a 404 error for a `ListView`, by changing the [**`allow_empty`** [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.allow_empty) attribute to `False`:

```
class OrderListView(ListView):

    template_name = 'orders/order_list.html'
    allow_empty = False

    def get_queryset(self):
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=self.kwargs['order_reference'],
        )
```

If we inspect the soure code of the `BaseListView` (a class that is one of the ancestors of the `ListView` class), then we see:

> ```
> class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
>     """A base view for displaying a list of objects."""
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
>         allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()
>
>         if not allow_empty:
>             # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
>             # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
>             # queryset in memory.
>             if self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists'):
>                 is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
>             else:
>                 is_empty = not self.object_list
>             if is_empty:
>                 raise Http404(_("Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.") % {
>                     'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
>                 })
>         context = self.get_context_data()
>         return self.render_to_response(context)
> ```

So it also takes pagination, etc. into account, and shifts the responsibility at the `get(..)` function level.

Comment: That's awesome, that's why I love Django! I should have checked here... they actually mention it: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_list_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

def get_queryset(self):
    my_objects = get_list_or_404(OrderItem, order__order_reference=self.kwargs['order_reference'])
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know that exists, thank you for that tip!